# PHP, checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a gallery where there are images and next to the images are checkboxes. When for exmaple user click 3 of checkboxex and a submit button i would like to save these 3 images in session to show them in the other gallery (of chose images). Now my code looks like this:

```
<?php if ($images->count()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?= $image['title'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $image['author'] ?></td>
                <td class="image">
                    <a href="static/images/<?= $image['file_name'] ?>">
                        <img class="gallery" src='static/images/<?= $image['file_name']?>'>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                <form action="gallery" method="post" class="wide"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $image['_id'] ?>"/>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckbox"/>
                    <input type="submit" name="gallery" value="Zapamiętaj"/>
                </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif ?>
```

It works but the problem is, that all images have own buttons and I would like to have one universal button to accept all clicked checkboxes. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to put the submit button outside of the `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="id**[]**" value="<?= $image['_id'] ?>"/>
```

If you change name of the input to "id[]", it means it will be an array named "id". In the PHP script gallery (form action), where you add it to session, you can do it like this:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST["id"] as $id){
  $_SESSION["selectedphotos"][] = $id;
  }
?>
```

EDIT: And you have to move form before foreach...

```
<?php if ($images->count()): ?>
    <form action="gallery" method="post" class="wide"/>
    <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?= $image['title'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $image['author'] ?></td>
            <td class="image">
                <a href="static/images/<?= $image['file_name'] ?>">
                    <img class="gallery" src='static/images/<?= $image['file_name']?>'>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $image['_id'] ?>"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="ckeckbox"/>
                <input type="submit" name="gallery" value="Zapamiętaj"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to move your form outside of the foreach loop. I also suggest you rename your checkbox input (hidden input is not usefull in this case but you can keep it if you want):

```
<?php if ($images->count()): ?>
    <form action="gallery" method="post" class="wide"/>
        <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
             <tr>
                <td><?= $image['title'] ?></td>
                <td><?= $image['author'] ?></td>
                <td class="image">
                    <a href="static/images/<?= $image['file_name'] ?>">
                        <img class="gallery" src='static/images/<?= $image['file_name']?>'>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $image['_id'] ?>"/>                    
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <input type="submit" name="gallery" value="Zapamiętaj"/>
    </form>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Would it be more `natural` to process the return `checkbox`  unique information  as `array values` rather than `array keys`? i.e. would it be easier to have the `unique_id` in the `checkbox value` instead of the `name`?

Comment: @Ryan Vincent Absolutly. This is another solution.